# Sending data through postman problem in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, postman

I am trying to send data through postman and it takes one field `null`. So anyone can help me with that. And also I am a beginner to Django.
this is the error

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "user_id"
>   violates not-null constraint DETAIL:  Failing row contains (6, MBBS,
>   Orenburg University, 2019, null).

My models are:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    gender_type = (('Male','Male'),('Female','Female'))
    user_name = (('Doctor','Doctor'),('Patient','Patient'))
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    user_type = models.CharField(choices=user_name, max_length=7)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=13,null=False)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=13,null=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    gender = models.CharField(choices=gender_type, max_length=10)
    blood_group = models.CharField(max_length=25,null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = MyUserManager()


USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

```
class Educations(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='edu_user')
    doctor_degree = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    university = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    passing_year = models.IntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.doctor_degree
```

here the user is for doctor and i'm taking it's `foreign key` in education model

And its viewset is:

```
class EducationViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def list(self,request):
        eduss=Educations.objects.all()
        edu_data_list=[]
        for edu in eduss:
            edu_data_list.append({
                "doctor_degree" : edu.doctor_degree,
                "university" : edu.university,
                "passing_year" : edu.passing.year,
                "doctor_name" : edu.user.full_name,
                "doctor_mobile_number": edu.user.mobile_number,
                "doctor_date_of_birth": edu.user.date_of_birth,
                "doctor_blood_group": edu.user.blood_group,
                "doctor_email": edu.user.email
            })
        return Response({"eduss":edu_data_list})
    def create(self,request):

        doctor_degree = request.data.get('doctor_degree')
        university = request.data.get('university')
        passing_year = request.data.get('passing_year')
        user = request.user
        education = Educations()
        education.doctor = user
        education.doctor_degree = doctor_degree
        education.university = university
        education.passing_year = passing_year
        education.save()
        return Response("successfully saved")
```

Comment: Where is your Myuser model? Please edit your question, format the code (using the Stackvoverflow format) Let us know when you edit. ok ?

Comment: You're trying to save an `Educations` object that hasn't got a `user` assigned. Your model has a field `user`, not `doctor`. So `eduction.doctor = user` doesn't actually do much (it just creates a new instance variable `doctor` but won't save it since it's not a field on your model).

Comment: @PauloHenrique now its in the format

Comment: @dirkgroten i have two user one is doctor and other is patient...and in MyUser model i have taken choice type for user

Comment: That's not relevant. You don't have a field `doctor` in your `Educations` model. You have a field `user`. So you should do `education.user = user` not `education.doctor = user`.

Comment: @dirkgroten getting this error :Cannot assign "<django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x7fadce9fbc18>": "Educations.user" must be a "MyUser" instance.

Comment: You're not logged in, so `request.user` is anonymous. You should probably check in your view first that the user is logged in, see [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users)